# Finding Entries in JSON objects

Tags: java, android, json

I've got this JSON in JSON object like this

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

I now want to get back "TRUE" (control F to find where that is)

> {"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"xmlns":"Lorum","xmlns$openSearch":"Ipsum","xmlns$gsx":"Dolor","id":{"$t":"Lorum"},"updated":{"$t":"2016-07-30T07:40:03.369Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"Ipsum","term":"Dolar"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Sheet1"},"link":[{"rel":"alternate","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"Lorum"},{"rel":"Ipsum","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"Dolor"},{"rel":"Lorum","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"Ipsum"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"Dolor"}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"spark"},"email":{"$t":"Lorum"}}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":"1"},"openSearch$startIndex":{"$t":"1"},"entry":[{"id":{"$t":"Ipsum"},"updated":{"$t":"2016-07-30T07:40:03.369Z"},"category":[{"scheme":"Dolor","term":"Lorum"}],"title":{"type":"text","$t":"Ipsum"},"content":{"type":"text","$t":"parko2: TRUE"},"link":[{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"Lorum"}],"gsx$parko1":{"$t":"TRUE"},"gsx$parko2":{"$t":"FALSE"},"gsx$indexfilteraanotisblankaarowsfilteraanotisblankaa":{"$t":""}}]}}

Comment: Hello. Please [edit] to add some more code with what you have already tried. It's worth mentioning that you have to start from the outer object, and work your way in towards the data you want

Comment: this may helps you : http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
JSONObject obj1 =obj.getJsonObject("feed");
JsonArray array = obj1.getJsonArray("entry");
```

> You will get array of entry array